# ruby on rails: rake not working with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I'm doing a tutorial following the Addison Wesley Ruby On Rails book and I'm currently learning about TDD. The problem is that I have a problem using rake after installing rspec, here's what I get from the terminal after trying "rake db:migrate":

```
    rake aborted!
undefined method `prerequisites' for nil:NilClass
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/rspec-rails.rb:10:in `load'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/rspec-rails.rb:10:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `instance_exec'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `each'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/Jay/rails_projects/sample_app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/Jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using rake 10.0.3 and rspec 2.0.1

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Please read your log message: `undefined method 'prerequisites' for nil:NilClass`. This means that there is no prerequisites `method/attributes`, because there is not class (the class don't exists). Make sure you have created a `model/class` with a method/attributes `prerequisites`. The run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858432/rake-aborted-undefined-method-prerequisites-for-nilnilclass

Comment: @hyperrjas is there any other way? I'm doing a tutorial step by step and at no point did it say to create any model, the main idea is to run a rspec test on the "spec/" files and it fails, the book states that in order to fix this I must use "rake" which results with this type of error.

Comment: @Mukesh I updated rsdoc and it didn't help

Comment: You must create a model on your `model` folder or under `lib` folder. Try it of this way

Comment: @hyperrjas should this model just have an empty 'prerequisites' definitition? That didn't work. I'm unclear how I'm supposed to make this model file, I'm just starting with ruby now and this tutorial is quite frustrating.

Comment: Remove before all migrations of your `db/migrate` folder. Now, for example run this on your console: `rails g model user prerequisites:string`. After run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: @hyperrjas I did exactly that and still I get the same message.

Comment: I can not see your app, but you must have some problem with your migrations, database. If you are newbie with rails, I recomend, clean your database or create a new project and create the model before begig with the tests.

Comment: @hyperrjas I've already made a new project twice and the problem begins after I add the rspec and/or autotests. Before that, rake seems to be working fine.

Comment: Remove autotest and check with guard!

Comment: @hyperrjas the problem arises in the projects after I add the following to my gemfile: "group :development do
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
end
group :test do
gem 'rspec', '2.0.1' gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end"

Comment: @hyperrjas actually I fixed it with deleting the group: development declaration, however now it won't create the "spec" folder. Ugh, rails is frustrating for beginners.

Comment: Okay fixed, I had to change the version in my gemfile. Thanks for trying to help. Admins should I delete this or keep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to a newer version of the rspec-rails gem to fix this issue.